# CAShapeLayer and SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make use of path animation feature in CAShapeLayer that is not available in SpriteKit and hence having to combine objects drawn suing CAShapeLayer with SpriteKit objects within the same view.

The coordinate system seems to be inverse: CAShapeLayer seems to have +ve y-axis pointing downwards, whereas SKScene has it pointing upwards.

Below is a simple XCODE playground that tries to draw a yellow line from 0,0 to 200,100 and shadow it with a thicker red line.

```
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 200)
let view = SKView(frame: bounds)
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view

// Create SK Scene
let scene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 400, height: 200))
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFit
view.presentScene(scene);

// Define the path
let path: CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath();
path.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:200, y:100))

// Use CAShapeLayer to draw the red line
var pathLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
pathLayer.path = path  
pathLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
pathLayer.fillColor = nil
pathLayer.lineWidth = 4.0
pathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel
pathLayer.zPosition = 1;
view.layer.addSublayer(pathLayer);

//Use SKShapeNode to draw the yellow line
let pathShape: SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode(path: path);
pathShape.strokeColor = .yellow;
pathShape.lineWidth = 1.0;
pathShape.zPosition = 10;
scene.addChild(pathShape);
```

I expected the yellow line to coincide with the red line. Whereas, the yellow and red lines appeared as mirror images.

Is there anyway to redefine the CAShapeLayer coordinate system to point +ve Y-axis upwards?

Comment: I was able to make the lines coincide by inverting the CAShapeLayer with an affine transform:  `var mirror = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: -1.0);   var inverse = path.copy(using: &mirror)!;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as written in the docs this is how it works, you may inverse the coordinates to match your requirements..

[Sprite kit docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skspritenode):

> The unit coordinate system places the origin at the bottom left corner of the frame and (1,1) at the top right corner of the frame. A sprite’s anchor point defaults to (0.5,0.5), which corresponds to the center of the frame.

[The rest of iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/CoordinateSystem.html):

> iOS. The default coordinate system has its origin at the upper left of the drawing area, and positive values extend down and to the right from it. **You cannot change the default orientation of a view’s coordinate system in iOS—that is, you cannot “flip” it.**